# Saving openJUMP data to be displayed in leaflet

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet, openjump

Using OpenJUMP, I've managed to create a road map layer split at every intersection of the lines (using the noder tool).

I need to take this data and display this using leaflet by using end coordinates of each of the split lines. How do I save the layer which has been split?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that you have two questions:

a) How to extract end points

b) How to save data for showing it in Leaflet.

For a) there is no native OpenJUMP tool but you can use the Sextante toolbox in OpenJUMP Plus. The tool is Sextante - Toolbox - Topology - Extract endpoints of lines. Tool extracts also start points but you can sort them out by having a look at the attributes of the new layer (isstart=0).

For b) OpenJUMP can only save layers well into shapefiles, JUMP JML, and KML. Use gdal for further conversion if needed. –  user30184 37 secs ago   edit